# Combine two strings in cloud functions?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

```
exports.helloGCS = (event, context) => {
  const gcsEvent = event;
  console.log(`Processing file: ${gcsEvent.name}`);
  const object = event.data;
 
  const filePath = gcsEvent.bucket;
  console.log(`Bucketname: ${gcsEvent.bucket}`);
```

I am trying to create the `const` variable named `filePath`,
I need the file path to be `gs://bucketname/filename`, however when I try

```js
const filePath = ('gs://${gcsEvent.bucket}/${gcsEvent.name}'); 
// the output in my log is 
gs://gcsEvent.bucket/gcsEvent.name
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Instead of ' try using the ` in your filePath

Answer (score 3):

```js
const filePath = (`gs://${gcsEvent.bucket}/${gcsEvent.name}`);
```

You want to use the ` instead of ' for it to be identified as a variables and not a string.